# Adding to existing policy in selinux

Tags: linux, security, selinux

I just created a custom policy and did the semodule -i test.te.

I reran all my tests after a few days and I noticed there were additional AVC denials in the audit.log.

I want to add the new stuff to my existing test.te file so that I won't have multiple policies. I just want to have one policy and just keep adding to it, is that possible and how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

All the procedure is very well documented in the manpages of `audit2allow(1)`, `checkmodule(8)` and`semodule(8)`.

An example workflow would be (**all** taken from the mentioned manpages):

- review local.te and customize as desired

```
$ cat local.te
  module local 1.0;
       require {
               class file {  getattr open read };
               type myapp_t;
               type etc_t;
        };
       allow myapp_t etc_t:file { getattr open read };
```

- Compile the module

```
$ checkmodule -M -m -o local.mod local.te
```

- Create the package

```
$ semodule_package -o local.pp -m local.mod
```

- Load the module into the kernel

```
$ semodule -i local.pp
```

- Install or replace a non-base policy package.

```
$ semodule -i httpd.pp
```

- List non-base modules.

```
$ semodule -l
```

If your modules are versioned, you might find interesting to use `semodule(8)` `-u` switch:

```
 -u,--upgrade=MODULE_PKG
   upgrade an existing module package, or install if the module does not exist
```

Comment: is it safe to reomve those pp file after you'Ve aded the policy?

Comment: Yes. You might want to keep the plain text `.te` files under version control.